# Django: using user.get_profile()

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I have a very newbie question on using django auth. Here is my model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    """ Main user profile used on a website """
    user            = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True) # reference to built in django user
    display_name    = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    # and several more fields

class Post(models.Model):
    """ Blog entry """
    author          = models.ForeignKey(User)
    tags            = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    title           = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    text            = models.TextField()
```

Trouble comes, when I want to output a list of posts:

```
#view
posts = Post.objects.all()
#template
{% for post in posts %}
    {{ post.title }} by {{ post.author.get_profile.display_name }}
{% endfor %}
```

For 100 posts this gives 101 queries, because every `get_profile()` goes to database to get the `display_name` field.

Is there a way to fix this? Can I use `select_related()`, or something? Or should I be referencing `UserProfile` istead of `User` in my `Post` model?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be able to use a `OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')` in your UserProfile model and then do `Post.objects.select_related('author__profile')`.

Comment: Thank you! `related_name` was the key!